# How to update fork with changes done by reviewers on a pull request on github?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository from base https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples

Made updates on a new branch and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/pull/2972)

The reviewers/collaborators suggested and made changes to files. I chose "Resolve Conversation" and can see the [changed files](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/pull/2972/files).

Questions:

1. How can i bring the changes done by reviewers on the PR 2972 into my local branch "ksurendra:helidon-mp-example-appengine-java11"?
2. And do i still need to get all the changed files into my local repository branch, verify and then "push" again to the PR 2972? Or do the reviewers already have the necessary changed files? If so, is it that i just need to update my repo/branch to have the updated files?

The details on [this page](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) are not clear enough.

Comment: just update your fork

Comment: "Resolve Conversation" doesn't apply the changes. Are you sure the changes have been applied? I still see the problematic lines in the changed files, and files to be removed are still there.

Comment: The common procedure is they comment, you apply the changes locally in "fixup" commits, then push those fixup commits, they approve them, then you squash the fixups and they merge.

Comment: I misunderstood. No code has been changed, the maintainers are discussing changes. You need to _make those code changes,_ then commit them, and push them, which will automatically update the PR.

Comment: thanks @msanford , this should be the correct process and did worked for me!

Comment: @SurenKonathala I updated my answer, if it worked you can do the usual with it. I left the rest for historical reasons because it may come up in searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the initial question.

No code has been changed: the maintainers are discussing and suggesting changes.

You need to make those code changes, on your branch, then commit them, and push them, which will automatically update the PR.

---

I initially completely misunderstood the problem. Given the title, I'll leave this answer below regardless.

If I had forked that repo and then cloned it locally, the very next thing I would do is

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples.git
```

This will create another [remote](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing) that points to the parent repository. `upstream` is not a special name, but it is a convention, just as `origin` is the convention for your fork.

Now, when changes are integrated into the original repository, I can quickly pull them into my local copy and push them to my fork:

```
git pull -r upstream <optional branch name if different from current branch>
```

List your remotes with

```
git remote -v
```

So in your case, you could pull directly from upstream into your branch

```
git checkout ksurendra:helidon-mp-example-appengine-java11
git pull upstream master
```

or update your local `master` and merge that:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream
git checkout ksurendra:helidon-mp-example-appengine-java11
git rebase master # Or git merge master
```

---

Keep in mind that git is a *distributed* version control system. This is precisely what "distributed" refers to: there is no central trunk - you could theoretically push and pull directly to your colleagues' workstations. It is simply not done for psychological simplicity.

The most common situation git is truly used in this distributed way is when maintaining forks: multiple (usually-complete) copies of repositories.

Comment: The problem is that the updates to files are in a Pull Request not in a remote branch. I need to bring these updates from PR into my forked branch.